# Conflict between arduino shield with 10 pin

Tags: arduino

Just beginning to to understand with arduino. I plan to put together a small device that accesses the internet at the site, and then, depending on the information that plays a mp3 file. From the annotation of to the Enternet Shield mp3 Shield and read that they both involve the 10-pin, and thus come into conflict. What to do in such a case, or is there an opportunity for playing time off Ethernet Shield and vice versa?

Answer (score 2):

I dont know about your mp3 shield but on the ethernet shield pin 10 is the Slave Select pin.
The MISO, MOSI, and CLK pins can be shered with other shields but not the SS pin.

The only way to solve this would be to cut the connector from the mp3 shiled and connect it to antother pin. Then you will also need to recompile the libs for your mp3 shield to reflect the change of pin.

For further information see [Arduino SPI](http://arduino.cc/en/Reference/SPI), [Arduino Ethernet](http://arduino.cc/en/Reference/Ethernet)